# Show recurrent clients in this query

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

I have a query that shows me the amount of client per amount of orders placed.

```
select quantidade_pedidos, count(*)
from (select count(*) as quantidade_pedidos, c.id
      from pedidos p inner join
           clientes c
           on p.cliente_id = c.id
      where p.aprovado = 1
      group by c.id
     ) x
group by quantidade_pedidos;
```

I want to make clients that have placed 2 orders be listed in 1, clients that have placed 3 orders be listed in 2 etc as well.

Now it only groups by number of orders:

1 order - 700 clients 
2 orders - 300 clients 
3 orders - 100 clients

Those 300 clients must appear in the 1 order to because they placed 1 order and 2 orders and those 100 clients must appear in the 2 orders group because they placed two orders.

How can I correct this query?
Sorry if it got a little bit confusing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand then what you want is to also group by the number of orders by adding a second group by.

```
select quantidade_pedidos, count(*) as order_count
from (select count(*) as quantidade_pedidos, c.id
      from pedidos p inner join
           clientes c
           on p.cliente_id = c.id
      where p.aprovado = 1
      group by c.id
     ) x
group by quantidade_pedidos, order_count;
```

Comment: Your query is wrong. 'Can't group on 'order_count''

Comment: Ah ha!  You're right.  Can you help me understand better what you're trying to do.  I don't think I quite have it.